# Update panel in Tab Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a tab container with 5 tabs, each tab contains an update panel.

When the user initially opens the form, they can only see the first Tab, the others are set to visible=false. Once they have completed the first form, the hit save which sends a partial postback to save the data to the DB. Once that is saved, I then want to set all the other tabs to visible, however this does not work at the moment, I am assuming because the tab container is not contained in an update panel.

How can I get this to work, do I need to put the tab container in it's own update panel, which will obviously then contain all the other update panels, or should I not use an update panel in the first tab and do a full page postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your page with nested update panels. As result you get an outer update panel for your tab container and for the existing inner update panels. Be aware that you need a PostbackTrigger for your inner update panels to update controls inside the outer update panel!

Google suggestion: Nested UpdatePanel

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to place all the tabs inside one update panel, otherwise you cannot update their visibility. Full page postback should not be necessary.